# Keyboard does not pops up in email modalviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I have been working on an iPad app. My app contains some PDF and some Videos. User can email any PDF or Video as an attachment to himself/herself by sending an email from the iPad. I have applied email functionality in this app. When user clicks on email, the email controller pops up. User has to write his/her email in the "TO" segment of email controller's recipient section. When user taps on "TO" segment to write the email address, the keyboard does not comes up in first tap. User has to tap several times for the keyboard to show up. This is an app wide issue. I have no idea why this is happening. Can anyone suggest why is it happening and how to fix it?

Rgds
PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have animations running that may be blocking user interaction with the app? if you do you can just set an option to allow user interaction within the animation options like so

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
       //some stuff
    } completion: NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are doing some heavy stuff and your main thread is overloaded. Try to stop unneeded routines before presenting your modalView. Especially any openGL rendering loop etc....